# Is there a way to trigger validation manually in monaco editor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, monaco-editor

I'm using the default TypeScript service and the models are initialized asynchronously with one model depending on the other. There's a case where the two models cannot detect each other so it shows a semantic error. If I make some edits in the dependent model, which causes the model to be re-validated, the errors disappear.

I have tried to setModel manually, which solves the problems. However, it destroys the undo history.

Is there a way to re-validate the model manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's my solution, which is extracted from [monaco-typescript](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-typescript):

```
async function revalidateModel(model) {
  if (!model || model.isDisposed()) return;

  const getWorker = await monaco.languages.typescript.getTypeScriptWorker();
  const worker = await getWorker(model.uri);
  const diagnostics = (await Promise.all([
    worker.getSyntacticDiagnostics(model.uri.toString()),
    worker.getSemanticDiagnostics(model.uri.toString())
  ])).reduce((a, it) => a.concat(it));

  const markers = diagnostics.map(d => {
    const start = model.getPositionAt(d.start);
    const end = model.getPositionAt(d.start + d.length);
    return {
      severity: monaco.MarkerSeverity.Error,
      startLineNumber: start.lineNumber,
      startColumn: start.column,
      endLineNumber: end.lineNumber,
      endColumn: end.column,
      message: flattenDiagnosticMessageText(d.messageText, "\n")
    };
  });
  const owner = model.getLanguageIdentifier().language;
  monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(model, owner, markers);
}
```

Call the function above when model is created asynchronizedly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to fix it:

```
setInterval(() => {
    const range = new monaco.Range(1,1,1,1);
    const addEmptySpace = {forceMoveMarkers: true, range, text: ' '};
    for (const m of monaco.editor.getModels()) {
        const toInvert = m.applyEdits([addEmptySpace]);
        m.applyEdits(toInvert);
    }
}, 50*1000)
```

Every fifty seconds you insert and immediately remove a space. I don't like it, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This could be a solution but it seems to affect undo history, too...